# Calculate days between dates in one field in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am relatively new to Access and have managed to work most things out but currently I am stuck. I need to calculate the numbers of days between dates stored in one date field. What I currently have is a query to show the officer, their case ref and the dates they took their actions.  What I need to know is the number of days between each action which I have shown as an extra column for example.

```
Officer     Reference       Date             Days Between Dates  
EL          1000225         03/10/2016       0
JE          1000225         01/11/2016       21
JE          1000225         02/02/2017       63
```

Is this something that I am able to achieve in Access. 
Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Select
    Officer,
    Reference,       
    [Date],
    DateDiff("d", 
        Max([Date]), 
        Nz((Select T.[Date] From YourTable
        Where T.Officer = YourTable.Officer
            And T.Reference = YourTable.Reference
            And T.[Date] < YourTable.[Date]), T.[Date])) As [Days Between Dates]
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you I did give this a try but it didn't work as I am taking info from 3 tables.  Might put it all into a holding table and try again.

Comment: You wrote, that you have a query, so use that.